# Retrieving options from a dynamically created Select form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have created a Dynamic HTML-Select whose options are populated by the names of the databases on my server. Upon clicking an option a new .php page is opened (using JQuery). In this new page I would like the database name selected from the previous page to passed as a string which I can use to do MySQL queries.

So what have I tried?

```
function selectDB() {
    $link = mysqli_connect ( 'username', 'root', '' );
    $qry = ("SHOW DATABASES");
    $db_list = mysqli_query ( $link, $qry );
    echo "<select name ='Databases' id='Databases' method='post'>";
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $db_list ) ) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row [0] . "'>" . $row [0] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('#Databases').change(function () {
    var yourDB = $(this).val();
    window.location.assign("test.php");
});
```

test.php

```
if (isset ( $_POST ['Databases'] )) {

    $dbName = $_POST ['Databases'];
    $link = mysqli_connect ( 'username', 'root', '', "'%$dbName%'" );
    if (! $link) {
        die ( "Connection failed" . mysqli_errno ( $link ) );
    }
    $qry = "SHOW tables";
    $tblist = mysqli_query ( $link, $qry );
    return $tblist;
    printf ( $tblist );
}
```

When I run this, I get the whitepageofdeath. Running `error_log` doesn't show anything. Where am I going wrong??

Comment: You're not sending anything via POST, so `$_POST` will be empty. Tack the database name to the end of your URL like a query string, `test.php?Databases=name_of_databases` and then use the `$_GET` array on the PHP side.

Comment: One other thing, remove the `%` characters surrounding the database name variable. Why do you have all of those quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the url to include the selection as a GET parameter

```
$('#Databases').change(function () {
    var yourDB = $(this).val();
    window.location.assign("test.php?db=" + yourDB);
});
```

The you can access it in your test.php page as a $_GET var

Comment: I tried your suggestion with the following code, but I still get a white screen.
`if (isset ( $_GET ['yourDB'] )) {
 $dbName = $_GET ['yourDB'];
 $link = mysqli_connect ( 'username', 'root', '', '$dbName' );
 if (! $link) {
  die ( "Connection failed" . mysqli_errno ( $link ) );
 }
 $qry = "SHOW tables";
 $tblist = mysqli_query ( $link, $qry );
 return $tblist;
 printf ( $tblist );
}`

Comment: the get var is db NOT yourDB

Comment: The parameter you are passing via the url is called 'db' in my example. So that it the name you need to use to retreive it in the php script, or whatever name you choose to give it.   "test.php?db="  if(isset($_GET['db']